# How to create Dialog box for Restarting in Win10 using Python

Tags: python

I am trying to run a Python script for the restart button on my taskbar. Here is the code I have:

```
import os
  
restart = input("Do you wish to restart your computer ? (yes / no): ")
  
if restart == 'no':
    exit()
else:
    os.system("shutdown /r /t 1")
```

I want to execute this outside of Python. Meaning when I click this button:
[image: shutdown icon]

I want it to say "Do you wish to restart your computer?" to confirm the restart instead of just doing it automatically.

Comment: You can't alter the behavior of the operating system icons.  Is that what you were asking?  You can certainly put your own icon on the desktop, and it put up a simple dialog, and then execute the "shutdown" command.  https://easygui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html

Comment: What is this button? How did you create it? How do you expect the Python code to run when you click on it? The question is really how this button will run the Python code and not the other way around so in order to help you, you should be asking about the way you implemented that button...

Comment: Personally, I'd rather do Windws-X, U, R from my keyboard to reboot Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help. Install PySimpleGUI first by running the following command:

```
pip install --upgrade PySimpleGUI
```

If it doesn't work, try:

```
pip3 install --upgrade PySimpleGUI
```

Run this code. It will simply open a window with two buttons: Shut down and Cancel. Just be sure you're ready to run it because it will shut down your machine. Save your work!

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import os

layout = [[sg.Button("Shut down", font='Lucida 14'), sg.Button('Cancel', font='Lucida 14', button_color=('white', 'firebrick3'))]]
window = sg.Window("Shutdown",layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == 'Cancel' or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    else:
        if event == 'Shut down':
            os.system('shutdown -s')
window.close()
```

You won't be able to use the system icons and button, though. This is your standalone app to shut down your machine. If you want it to run outside Python, you need to create an executable file (.exe). In order to do that, you need to install PyInstaller.

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

or

```
pip3 install pyinstaller
```

Check out their website. It explains in detail how to do it.
https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/

Comment: Thank you, going to try this!

Comment: @LowendTheory If you find the answer useful, please vote up and check it as answered. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

All you need in python to restart is `exec('shutdown -r')` idk how you want to make a button...

you can create a dialog with python's builtin input feature:

```
prompt = input("do Something")
if prompt == "yes":
  print("done")
else:
  print("not done")
```

Comment: thanks, i basically created a shortcut for restarting the computer and pinned it to my taskbar. What i would like is to receive a prompt "do you wish to restart the computer?" after clicking the shortcut. i thought there would be a way to implement this.